# Gio SimpleAction to call a function

Tags: python, gtk3, gio

I have made menu using Gio action in a Gtk3 app.
The menu item is created as:

```
#in main file
MenuElem = menu.MenuManager
# Open Menu
action = Gio.SimpleAction(name="open")
action.connect("activate", MenuElem.file_open_clicked)
self.add_action(action)
```

The `file_open_clicked` is in `menu.py`, `class MenuManager`, defined as:

```
import gi
import pybib
import view
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class MenuManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parsing = pybib.parser()
        self.TreeView = view.treeview()
    #file_open_clicked
    #in menu.py
    def file_open_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open an existing fine", None,
                                       Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
                                       (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,
                                        Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                                        Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
        response = dialog.run()
        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            filename = dialog.get_filename()
            dialog.destroy()
            self.TreeView.bookstore.clear()
            self.TreeView.viewer(self.parsing.booklist)
            # self.TreeView.view.set_model()
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("Cancel clicked")
            dialog.destroy()
```

I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rudra/Devel/mkbib/Python/src/menu.py", line 81, in file_open_clicked
    self.TreeView.bookstore.clear()
AttributeError: 'SimpleAction' object has no attribute 'TreeView'
```

I know `SimpleAction` takes one more option, and `TreeView` should be called.
But I dont know how.
Kindly help

Comment: Please show more enclosing code, specificall the definition of the `MenuElem` class.

Comment: updated. Please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me break down your code for you.

```
#in main file
MenuElem = menu.MenuManager
```

Here you set `MenuElem` to point to `menu.MenuManager` class. Probably you meant to initialize the object here such that `MenuElem` become an **instance** of the `menu.MenuManager`class. Such that the `__init__` function of the `MenuManager` class was called. Thus the code should be:

```
#in main file
MenuElem = menu.MenuManager()
```

Then the next part where something goes wrong is in here:

```
def file_open_clicked(self, widget):
```

If we check the [docs](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gio-2.0/classes/SimpleAction.html#Gio.SimpleAction.signals.activate) for the `activate` signal we see that it has 2 parameters. So currently without initializing the object `self` is set to the first parameter namely the `SimpleAction` and the `widget` is set to the activation `parameter`.

But as we now have initialized the `MenuManager` object, the `file_open_clicked` function will get 3 input parameters namely `self`, `SimpleAction` and `parameter`. Thus we need to accept them all like this:

```
def file_open_clicked(self, simpleAction, parameter):
```

Now the code will work as `self` is actually an object with the attribute `TreeView`. (Just for your information in Python variables and attributes are normally written in lowercase)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `TreeView` attribute only exists on the `MenuManager` class, whereas, when you call the `file_open_clicked` method, the first argument (`self`) is the `SimpleAction` object created. Using the `file_open_clicked` method of a **`MenuManager` instance** would fix this.

```
menu_manager = MenuManager()
action = Gio.SimpleAction(name="open")
action.connect("activate", menu_manager.file_open_clicked)
```

Comment: That is what I have done...see, file_open_clicked is called with `MenuElem` instance.